# Error 5 Input/Output When trying to install Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, hard-drive

I am using a Lenovo laptop without a CD drive. I tried to install Ubuntu  12.04 through USB stick. After completing around 20% or 22% i got error like `Error 5 Input/Output`. Please help me, I am struggling for more than a week.

No. Its not working. Again it shows the same error. Please help. And also i don't know how to partition the hard disk. If i tried to add partition. It shows `No root is defined.....`

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs mostly when the USB-Stick isn't installed correctly. I would format the USB-Stick completely and then install it again.